# Android Titanium - ImageView doesn't show a remote image

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-android

I have to download a remote image and show it in a ImageView. In iOS works prefectly but in Android doesn't work. The image size is 190x190, and the url is correct because the same url works in iOS. This is my code:

View:

```
<ScrollView id="scrollView" showVerticalScrollIndicator="true">
   <Label id="titleLabel"></Label>
   <ImageView id="qr"></ImageView>

   <View id="codigoView">
      <Label id="codigoLabel"></Label>
      <Label id="numeroLabel"></Label>
   </View>

   <Button id="condicionesButton" onClick="condicionesAction"></Button>
   <Button id="localizacionButton" onClick="localizacionAction"></Button>
   <Button id="emailButton" onClick="emailAction"></Button>
</ScrollView>
```

Style:

```
"#qr":{
    top: 5,
    width: 190,
    height: 190
}
```

Controller:

```
var qrString = args.get('qrcode');
$.qr.image = Alloy.Globals.qr_url + qrString;

$.qr.addEventListener('load', function(e){
    alert('Picture loaded');
});
```

This alert does never showed.

The url is:

> https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=190x190&data="akjlsdfkjalskdjfal"

And the image is a png.

My [question](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/183110/android---imageview-doesnt-show-a-remote-image) in Appcelerator Q&A

**EDIT:**

This can cause the problem?

> For Android, if there is a redirect and change in protocol, it will not
>   follow. For example, from http to https and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to implement your example, and anything works fine, both on iOS and Android!

This is **index.xml** (view):

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <ImageView id="qr"/>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And this is **index.js** (controller):

```
$.qr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert('picture loaded');
});
$.qr.image = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=190x190&data=akjlsdfkjalskdjfal"
$.index.open();
```

There are no problems of any type: no redirects and no changes in the used protocol! Anything seems to be ok.

Your problem is probably due to the fact that you add the EventListener **after** the operation that can fire the event! Indeed, if the event 'load' is fired very soon there is nothing which is listening for it!!

Even if the problem is not caused by that, remember to add the EventListener **always before** the lines which could fire the event!

Comment: Yes, my example works both on the Android and iOS emulator! Try to run it! Do you still have problems?

Comment: Yes, I have problems with it. I'm running in a device, no simulator.... I'm going to try with an emulator

Comment: What heigth and width put you in your ImageView? I can't show it on Android.

Comment: You don't need to choose height/width... In my example the ImageView is inside a Window, so the height/width is automatically put to Titanium.UI.SIZE (it adapts to the image's height/width).

Comment: could you please implement exactly my example, opening a new project? So that we can understand if there is something wrong with your code or something else...

Comment: with your code it doesn't work too. This error appear: SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: where have you tried my code? Simulator or device? Tell me something more about your environment...

Comment: Device, always in a device. Titanium SDK 3.5.0.GA, Android 4.2.0

Comment: Sorry, Android 4.4.2. The API v21

Comment: the only difference is that i'm running the last version of Titanium (4 instead of 3.5)... is it possible for you to update it or not?

Comment: with Titanium sdk 4.0.0.GA works! I want to try to change my app sdk but I tried previously and the app give me problems...

Comment: Thank you for help me :)

Comment: My android actionbar theme doesn't work in sdk 4.0.0.GA that's the problem :(

Comment: open another question with all the necessary details and we'll work on it

Comment: Yes, I did. Another question is opened